# How do I display name in column2 dependent on value in column1?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am doing an inventory for all the businesses of a street. I have a two sheets, where on one I have different categories for commercial uses.

Each category displayed in sheet 1 has a number (1 to 132), and right of that number is the name of the category. Sample sheet:

[image]

In sheet 2, when I enter for example "5" in column 1, I would like to have that linked to sheet 1 so that in column 2 excel automatically displays the name of the category: "pharmacie".

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are here to help by answering your questions about what you have tried and gotten stuck. We are not here to do it for you. Please tell us what you have tried, researched so far, and what problem you are having.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not an expert and I've tried "VLOOKUP", no clue how to make it work. "IF" was no help either. I search all over your forums, but the how-to to this (in appearance) simple operation can't be found anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a lookup function. In your case `VLOOKUP` would work just fine.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I had tried it already but I could not make it work; this time, great success!

Comment: No problem, I'm pleased it worked for you.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little to show how to solve the problem (like an example)?  Just mentioning a function might be enough to help this person, but it might not be useful to someone new to Excel.  Thanks.